# Python - colorsys.hsv_to_rgb returning a float value

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is `hsv_to_rgb` returning a float value for this? and only for g and b?

```
import colorsys
from colorsys import *

colorRGB = (255,0,255)
print(colorRGB)
colorHSV = rgb_to_hsv(colorRGB[0],colorRGB[1],colorRGB[2])
colorRGB = hsv_to_rgb(colorHSV[0],colorHSV[1],colorHSV[2])
print(colorRGB)
```

(255, 0, 255)
(255, 0.0, 255.0)
[Finished in 0.0s]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

> You need to **rescale RGB values** 0 to 255 between **0 to 1** first.
>   Section **Code Modification** below gives you a modified version of your code that will run *bug-free*.

If you try this, you would realize what is happening.

```py
# we provide r, g, b values ranging between 0 and 1 for each.
colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(*colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(1,0,0))
```

**Output**:

```sh
(1, 0.0, 0.0)
```

### Code Modification

I would change your code as follows (rescale 0-255 between 0-1):

```py
from colorsys import hsv_to_rgb, rgb_to_hsv

colorRGB = (255,0,255)
colorRGB = tuple(x/255 for x in colorRGB)

print(f'colorRGB: {colorRGB}')
colorHSV = rgb_to_hsv(*colorRGB)
colorRGB = hsv_to_rgb(*colorHSV)
print(f'colorRGB: {colorRGB}')
```

**Output**:

```sh
colorRGB: (1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
colorRGB: (1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

Comment: @RenaudFutterer Let me know if you have any questions. Please consider **`accepting`** the solution if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

If You explore `colorsys` library code, You will observe function `rgv_to_hsv` and `hsv_to_rgv` code. You will observe there are multiple divisions and float multiplication happening. **This is the reason it is library is returning float value**.

#### You can convert float to int as:

```
colorRGB = list(map(int, hsv_to_rgb(colorHSV[0],colorHSV[1],colorHSV[2])))
```